# Apache Nutch indexing error in Solr

Tags: search-indexing, web-crawler, apache-solr

```
Indexing 1000/1000 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexing 1000/1000 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
Indexer: java.lang.RuntimeException: Indexing job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:150)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:240)

Error running:
  /Users/devharsh/Downloads/nutch/bin/nutch index -Dsolr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch Crawl/crawldb -linkdb Crawl/linkdb Crawl/segments/20200331192240
Failed with exit value 255.
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.. I figured out in Solr the core 'nutch' was not mapped so I created a new core named 'nutch' from Solr > Core admin (http://localhost:8983/solr/#/) (created new folder named nutch and copied schema files) and it worked..